# R: Error: Objects of type numeric not supported by autoplot

Tags: r, plot

Below function gives error:

```
autoplot(melsyd[,'Economy.Class']) +
  ggtitle("Economy class passengers: Melbourne-Sydney") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Thousands")

Error: Objects of type numeric not supported by autoplot.
```

Brief about the dataframe:

```
 melsyd = read.csv("http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/FIN%20335/Datasets/MelSyd.csv")

> head(melsyd,2)
  First.Class Business.Class Economy.Class
1       1.912             NA        20.167
2       1.848             NA        20.161
```

Please help. I am trying to plot Economy class values against time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the "fpp" package first. This package includes all data used in the "Forecasting: Principle and Practice".

install.packages("fpp")
library(fpp)

then you can apply autoplot to melsyd.